# Why does only one of my functions in onClick execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to call two methods when a tab on my navigation bar is clicked.  I originally only had one method being called until I realized that I needed to call the second one to update my data.  The problem is that when I try and call both methods, only one of them is executed and never both.  I've had multiple functions in an onClick method before and they work fine but I'm a little confused why this way isn't working.  Any help would be great, thanks!

app.js

```
export default Class App extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  this.state = {
   OpenJobsDB: [],
   PendingJobsDB: [],
   CompletedJobsDB: [],
   page: undefined,
  };

  this.setPage = this.setPage.bind(this);
  this.PullJobsTables = this.PullJobsTables.bind(this);
 }
}
    PullJobsTables() {
        console.log("pulling jobs from DB");

        socket.emit('selectFromJobsWhereOpenAwaitingETAsAssigned', function (result) {
            this.setState({ OpenJobsDB: result });
        }.bind(this));

        socket.emit('selectFromJobsWherePending', function (result) {
            this.setState({ PendingJobsDB: result });
        }.bind(this));

        socket.emit('selectFromJobsWhereCompleteDeleted', function (result) {
            this.setState({ CompletedJobsDB: result });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    setPage(e) {
        console.log("inside setpage");
        var naviBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('NavigationBarButtons');
        for (var i = 0; i < naviBtns.length; i++) {
            naviBtns[i].style.backgroundColor = '#333a56';
            naviBtns[i].style.bottomBorder = '0';
        }
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#e14658';
        e.target.style.bottomBorder = '3px solid #FFA279';

        const page = e.target.name;
        this.setState(() => ({ page }))
        this.OpenNavigationBar('close');
        this.setState({
            showReportsList: false,
            showTablesList: false,
            showTimeOff: false,
        });
    }
}
```

My onClick looks like this

```
<button onClick{() => {this.setPage.bind(this); this.PullJobsTables.bind(this);}}
```

In this example the only one that get's called is the PullJobsTables method and not the setPage method.  This is the way I've done it in similar situations and it works fine.  This is kind of confusing me as to why it's not calling both.

Comment: Both those functions already had `this` bound to them in your constructor. You also do not pass the event to the callbacks.

Comment: you can just call `PullJobsTables` from `setPage` function directly.  Also by doing this `this.setPage.bind(this); this.PullJobsTables.bind(this);` you are not calling a function rather just binding `this` which dont seem like required since you are already doing it in your constructor

Comment: calling these socket emits every time a page is loaded only execute once correct?

Comment: `.bind()` does not call the functions, it just creates a new one with the context (`this`) set to the parameter of `bind`. Also, you could remove every use of `bind` and just use arrow functions everywhere since you're already using them sparingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those functions already had `this` bound to them in your constructor. You also need to pass the event to the callbacks that are expecting it.

```
<button
  onClick={event => {
    this.setPage(event);
    this.PullJobsTables();
  }}
>
```

Comment: This works.  I don't want to put the PullJobsTables method inside the setPage method because then it performs the socket emits every time I move to a new page.  This is the exact way I was looking for.  I just was forgetting to pass the event to the setPage method.